# Table for priorities?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am curious to know if there is a way to make a table based off priorities?

As in you have a form, subform (datasheet), and 2 buttons.

The subform takes data from a query which takes data from a table.

From here, the query shows projects. You can select the project on the subform and click a button to dec priority, which moves it DOWN on the list by 1 project. If you click the inc button, it moves it UP. If it's at the very bottom and you click the decrease button it will pop up saying "This project is already the lowest priority!" same with the increase, but it'll say it's already the highest.

Is this possible? I really don't know any VBA to access a subform's datasheet and modify it, and I'd like to learn.

UPDATE:
I have 1 table, with 5 priority types, and 1 key.
The table is named ProjectsT, the key is named ProjectID and the 5 priorities are:
CuttingPriority, ProjPriority, EngineerPriority, CutplanPriority, HardwarePriority. Each priority is listed as a number datatype.

This is one set of code I have so far for the buttons from an answer below:
Up button:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intSavePos As Integer
Dim intSavePosMin As Integer
Dim intSavePosMax As Integer

'Save start and end value (It's assumed you start with 1 ! The value 0 (zero) is used for swapping value's)
intSavePosMin = DMin("CuttingPriority", "ProjectsT")
intSavePosMax = DMax("CuttingPriority", "ProjectsT")
'When the subform is linked to a keyfield use that field for a WHERE like:
'intSavePosMin = DMin("sequence", "tblTableNico5038", "Function='" & Me.sfrmFunctionTables.Form.Function & "'")
'intSavePosMax = DMax("sequence", "tblTableNico5038", "Function='" & Me.sfrmFunctionTables.Form.Function & "'")

intSavePos = Me.txtCuttingPriority
'is it the first ? ==> no action
If intSavePos = intSavePosMin Then Exit Sub
'switch positions
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
strSQL = "UPDATE ProjectsT SET ProjectsT.CuttingPriority = 0 WHERE CuttingPriority=" & intSavePos & ";"
'When the subform is linked to a keyfield use that field for a WHERE like:
'strSQL = "UPDATE tblTableNico5038 SET tblTableNico5038.Sequence = 0 WHERE Function='" & Me.sfrmTableNico5038.Form.Function & "' AND sequence=" & intSavePos & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
strSQL = "UPDATE ProjectsT SET ProjectsT.CuttingPriority = " & intSavePos & " WHERE CuttingPriority=" & intSavePos - 1 & ";"
'When the subform is linked to a keyfield use that field for a WHERE like:
'strSQL = "UPDATE tblTableNico5038 SET tblTableNico5038.Sequence = " & intSavePos & " WHERE Function='" & Me.sfrmTableNico5038.Form.Function & "' AND sequence=" & intSavePos - 1 & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
strSQL = "UPDATE ProjectsT SET ProjectsT.CuttingPriority = " & intSavePos - 1 & " WHERE CuttingPriority=0;"
'When the subform is linked to a keyfield use that field for a WHERE like:
'strSQL = "UPDATE tblTableNico5038 SET tblTableNico5038.Sequence = " & intSavePos - 1 & " WHERE Function='" & Me.sfrmTableNico5038.Form.Function & "' AND sequence=0;"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.Refresh
Me.ProjectsTCuttingSubF.SetFocus
SendKeys ("{up}")
```

Down button:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intSavePos As Integer
Dim intSavePosMin As Integer
Dim intSavePosMax As Integer

intSavePosMin = DMin("CuttingPriority", "ProjectsT")
intSavePosMax = DMax("CuttingPriority", "ProjectsT")

intSavePos = Me.txtCuttingPriority
'is it the last ? ==> no action
If intSavePos = intSavePosMax Then Exit Sub
'switch positions
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
strSQL = "UPDATE ProjectsT SET ProjectsT.CuttingPriority = 0 WHERE CuttingPriority=" & intSavePos & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
strSQL = "UPDATE ProjectsT SET ProjectsT.CuttingPriority = " & intSavePos & " WHERE CuttingPriority=" & intSavePos + 1 & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
strSQL = "UPDATE ProjectsT SET ProjectsT.CuttingPriority = " & intSavePos + 1 & " WHERE CuttingPriority=0;"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.Refresh
Me.ProjectsTCuttingSubF.SetFocus
SendKeys ("{down}")
```

--

Comment: How many records are we talking about, and how are they entered (manually through the table or through a form)?  As long as you account for assigning a priority to newly created records and deal with the gaps left by deleted records, you should be ok.  It _will_ require some VBA.

Comment: We are talking about hundreds (in the future). People add new records with a form; though I'm sure there would be a way to check which the highest number is in the priority fields in the main table and then set the priority to the next number up on add.

Answer (score 3):

I was curious to see if I could come up with a solution that didn't resort to "SQL glue-up". The result is available for download [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=23D4288415AFC5C8!204&authkey=!AI_tb2NrXcwrti8) (Access 2010 or later).

The key components are a [Managers] table

```
ID  ManagerName
--  --------------
 1  Thompson, Gord
 2  Elk, Anne
```

a [Projects] table

```
ID  ManagerID  Description           Priority
--  ---------  --------------------  --------
 1          1  buy bacon                    1
 2          1  wash the car                 2
 3          1  clean out the garage         3
 4          2  test1                        1
 5          2  test2                        2
```

two saved parameter queries (`QueryDef`s) to locate the next highest/lowest-priority project

[GetHigherPriorityProject]

```sql
PARAMETERS prmManagerID Long, prmCurrentPriority Long;
SELECT TOP 1 Projects.ID, Projects.Priority
FROM Projects
WHERE (((Projects.Priority)<[prmCurrentPriority]) 
    AND ((Projects.ManagerID)=[prmManagerID]))
ORDER BY Projects.Priority DESC , Projects.ID;
```

[GetLowerPriorityProject]

```sql
PARAMETERS prmManagerID Long, prmCurrentPriority Long;
SELECT TOP 1 Projects.ID, Projects.Priority
FROM Projects
WHERE (((Projects.Priority)>[prmCurrentPriority]) 
    AND ((Projects.ManagerID)=[prmManagerID]))
ORDER BY Projects.Priority, Projects.ID;
```

one more saved parameter query to update the priority of a given project

[SetProjectPriority]

```sql
PARAMETERS prmNewPriority Long, prmID Long;
UPDATE Projects SET Projects.Priority = [prmNewPriority]
WHERE (((Projects.ID)=[prmID]));
```

a dead-simple Class just to hold a couple of Properties

[projectInfo]

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private pID As Long, pPriority As Long

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = pID
End Property

Public Property Let ID(Value As Long)
    pID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Priority() As Long
    Priority = pPriority
End Property

Public Property Let Priority(Value As Long)
    pPriority = Value
End Property
```

a rudimentary form with a subform

[image: ManagersForm.png]

and the code behind that form

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdMoveDown_Click()
    AdjustPriority "lower"
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMoveUp_Click()
    AdjustPriority "higher"
End Sub

Private Sub AdjustPriority(Direction As String)
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim currentProjectID As Long, otherProject As projectInfo

    Set rst = Me.ProjectsSubform.Form.RecordsetClone
    rst.Bookmark = Me.ProjectsSubform.Form.Recordset.Bookmark
    currentProjectID = rst!ID
    Set otherProject = GetOtherProject(rst!ManagerID, rst!Priority, Direction)
    If otherProject.ID = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There is no project with a " & Direction & " priority."
    Else
        Set cdb = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("SetProjectPriority")
        ' swap priorities
        qdf!prmNewPriority = rst!Priority
        qdf!prmID = otherProject.ID
        qdf.Execute
        qdf!prmNewPriority = otherProject.Priority
        qdf!prmID = currentProjectID
        qdf.Execute
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set cdb = Nothing
        Me.ProjectsSubform.Requery
        ' now restore the previous current record in the subform
        Set rst = Me.ProjectsSubform.Form.RecordsetClone
        rst.FindFirst "ID=" & currentProjectID
        Me.ProjectsSubform.Form.Recordset.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set otherProject = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function GetOtherProject(prmManagerID As Long, _
        prmCurrentPriority As Long, _
        Direction As String) As projectInfo
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rtn As New projectInfo

    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    If Direction = "higher" Then
        Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("GetHigherPriorityProject")
    Else
        Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("GetLowerPriorityProject")
    End If
    qdf!prmManagerID = prmManagerID
    qdf!prmCurrentPriority = prmCurrentPriority
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rst.EOF Then
        rtn.ID = 0
        rtn.Priority = 0
    Else
        rtn.ID = rst!ID
        rtn.Priority = rst!Priority
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Set GetOtherProject = rtn
    Set rtn = Nothing
End Function
```

**EDIT re: comment**

> is there a way to make it automatically add the next priority number on the list if you are adding a record through another form?

Yes. I forgot to mention that in the existing sample solution there is a `Before Change` Data Macro on the [Projects] table to do just that:

```
If [IsInsert] Then
    If Not IsNull([ManagerID]) Then
        SetField
            Name      Priority
            Value =   Nz(DMax("Priority", "Projects", "ManagerID=" & [ManagerID]), 0) + 1
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I like this overall.  Should the Move Up button be enabled when the selected item is already the top priority ... if so, what should the button do in that case?  (I'll download the sample file next; perhaps my answer is in there.)

Comment: @HansUp In that case (as in the question's "spec"), clicking the "Move Up" button triggers a `MsgBox` that says something along the lines of "there is nothing more important than buying bacon". ;)

Comment: Woot!  (What about beer?!)

Comment: This looks perfect, except for the fact I am quite dumb. Everything seems to be straight forward, but what do I change in the code to apply to my database? I got the most basic of stuff (such as changing the subform name in the GetOtherProject & AdjustPriority functions/subs and changing some of the things in the queries, though I am not sure if I changed the right ones. My database has 1 table that holds all the information needed for the priorities; and there will be 4 separate priorities for 5 different types of things. Each type will have a different form for the organization,

Comment: I really should have mentioned that in the OP. The priorities are called CuttingPriority, ProjPriority, EngineerPriority, CutplanPriority, and HardwarePriority. Each "Project" has an ID (The key) called ProjectID). These are all located under 1 table named ProjectsT. Also, with this is there a way to make it automatically add the next priority number on the list if you are adding a record through another form? Lets say the highest number in all priorities is 55 and you add a new record, all the priorities in the new record would be 56. Lets say they are 55,56,57,58, and 59 the new one would be

Comment: 56,57,58,59, and 60. So far I think this is the best answer, so I will give you an up vote until it's fully solved. Thank you for all your hard work!

Comment: @D347HxD re: "is there a way to make it automatically add the next priority number on the list if you are adding a record through another form?" - Yes. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have edited the code to pertain to my 1 table (instead of using 2)... though that leads me to the problem of when I run the up button command I get: `Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)` being highlighted in the GetOtherProject function, with the error: Too few parameters expected 3.

Comment: @D347HxD It stands to reason that if you make tweaks to the VBA code you may have to make a corresponding adjustment to the saved parameter queries. (They are code, too, just in a slightly different form.)

Comment: Okay, I did the changes and now for the up and down button it says "There are no project with a (higher/lower) priority" even if there are projects above and below it.

Comment: @D347HxD So now you need to check the logic in the saved queries to find out why they never return any records.

Comment: Assuming the saved queries are GetHigherPriorityProject and GetLowerPriorityProject, then I honestly have no clue what could be wrong... all the code seems fine, and all I changed was the variable names.

Comment: `PARAMETERS prmProjectID Long, prmCurrentPriority Long;`

`SELECT TOP 1 ProjectsT.ProjectID, ProjectsT.CuttingPriority`

`FROM ProjectsT`

`WHERE (((ProjectsT.CuttingPriority)<[prmCurrentPriority]) AND ((ProjectsT.ProjectID)=[prmProjectID]))`

`ORDER BY ProjectsT.CuttingPriority DESC , ProjectsT.ProjectID;` is the code for the gethigherpriority query.

Comment: @D347HxD I don't know to what extent your table structure might be different from mine, but in my sample app that query was being passed a `ManagerID` (foreign key) and a `Priority`. Now it is being passed a `ProjectID` and a `Priority`. If [ProjectID] is the primary key of [ProjectsT] then that would explain why the query never returns any rows.

Comment: It is indeed the primary key from ProjectsT. I only have 1 table, named ProjecsT. This table has the primary key named ProjectID, and CuttingPriority as the priority number.

Comment: @D347HxD Then if I'm interpreting that query correctly what it is trying to do is "find a record in [ProjectsT] that has the same [ProjectID] as the current record but has a higher (numerically smaller) [Priority] than the current record". That, of course, will never happen.

Comment: @D347HxD Remove the `AND ((ProjectsT.ProjectID)=[prmProjectID])` part of the WHERE clause so you only consider the [CuttingPriority] of the other records.

Comment: Okay, I am no longer getting that error, but now am getting a `"The experssion On Click you entered as the even property setting produced the following error: Method or data member not found."`

Answer (score 0):

I have a work ticket system in my work place and to create priorities I created two tables: `Work_Tickets` and `Work_Ticket_Criteria`.  The criteria table has a list of low, low-medium, etc... and a field in `Work_Tickets` pulls from that 2nd table.  Then sort by date.

It doesn't give a single ticket a numerical priority like you are looking for because to do that I believe you would have to create a separate field and then modify the numerical field of each record after every update.  Switch 1 with 2, or make the new record 1 and then add 1 to each and every record's priority field to move them down the list.

Or if you start with a number like 1000 then you can make records more or less than 100 in increments of 5, 10, or 20 but then you'll eventually run out of numbers...

***Update***

If you're willing to go my method of adding another column, then I would just add column and name the field `Priority_Numbers` or something.  Then you would mark each as 1 - whatever but you may want to make check to make sure your number doesn't already exist by making it a key or giving it a check.

Then each time you would want to view your tickets you would use something like:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim myR As Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE criteria_here ORDER BY Priority_Numbers ASC"

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

And bam you have your prioritized list.

Now to change the priority you would need to select that recordset, do a findfirst to get the record with the value you want replaced, +1 or -1 to each priority number in a `While not EOF` loop and keep moving next.  This will become tedious if your tickets become too high I'm sure.

Comment: I see that as a way of doing it, yes, but I am looking for a way to modify the table in general so I don't have to make a new column or other table. So when you click the button all it does it move it down on the current table (which modifies it in the query, which would have to save it's location on the main table) so when you close it and come back it'll be in the same order?

Comment: A table, by definition, has no defined order is the problem here.  You have to define what to prioritize it by (autonumber, alphabetical, etc.)  So to move a record 'up and down' you need something to sort it by.

Comment: It seems better to use the Autokey. How would I do this?

Comment: You would only be able to query the autokey you could not modify it.  That would defeat the purpose of it automatically numbering itself.

Comment: Okay, so I would have to make a new column then. What type of code would I use to change the number of the selected field down or up, and change the others accordingly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `While not EOF`

Comment: EOF = end of file.  When looping through a recordset, it will continue to loop until you get to the last record.  Once it tries moves beyond the last record it is considered the end of file and will break the loop.  **Make sure you're adding the .movenext or else you will enter the infinite loop.**

Comment: Would you be able to write up a mock code of what you mean? Just to outline it.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the ENTIRE conversation here:

[re-order a records sequence using up and down buttons](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.access.formscoding/re-order-a-records-sequen/63440)

You're going to need at aleast a mediocre understanding of VBA and how to apply your specific data to a pre-existing example.  This person was looking to do almost precisely what your question describes, and the person who was working with him was an Access MVP.  I say to read through the entire conversation because there were several iterations and tweaks performed over the course of the solution.

If you have any specific questions after integrating this solution, feel free to come back and ask.

Comment: Will read and any questions I have I'll ask here, also if it ends up working I'll be back to mark it as such.

Comment: @D347HxD - You can also download the sample database at http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=121711 posted by MissingLinq.  It does what you want and you can probably just tweak the code there easier than on the first example I gave you.

Comment: I will probably end of reading it all just so I can learn how to do it as well as tweak it. If this whole conversation gets me stumped, then I will probably download the sample database. Aha.

Comment: Johnny, I just got the chance to finish looking at the conversation and I am confused why there is code behind a combo box, do I need this combo box? For what I am wanting I shouldn't need a combo box...

What I am wanting is to select the project from the subform directly and be able to click the button up/down and it does the respective thing.

Comment: Also I just opened up the sample database and played with it. I added the code to my database, and it moves the CuttingPriority number but doesn't sort the subform table by the order of the priorities (1->2->3->etc)

Comment: That should be solved by making sure the subform has an "ORDER BY" in its recordset, and then just refreshing the subform.

Comment: So ORDER BY CuttingPriority & Me.Requery in the button's code?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what is going on now. I push the up or down button, it switches the place of the respective button pushed (lets say we pushed the down button) Lets say the highlighted field is set as the priority 5 and the one below it is 6. When I click down, it switched the one highlighted to 6 and the one below it to 5. It worked! Though there is a problem... if I push down again it switches the ones just switched back to normal and highlights priority 7. It seems like it's almost working though, this is the only problem.

Comment: Looked further into it... it doesn't change the priority number, only moves it down one then if you push it again resets the order and selects the one below it.

Comment: Also, it only moves the number and not the whole field.

Comment: You only want to change the CuttingPriority and then re-sort the subform based on CuttingPriority.  I haven't really picked that example database apart to see exactly what it's doing, but I clicked the Up/Down buttons and it worked properly so there's got to be something you overlooked when you converted it to work with your dataset.

Comment: yeah, it's working perfectly from the example but I've looked up and down the code I ported for errors and I see none. Let me copy paste my code in the OP.